# rosmake fails with c++/clang errors

Tags: c++, rosmake, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running `rosmake -a --pre-clean` on OS X (10.8.2) gives the following build log, with errors concerning some nasty C++ code and a few clang errors too.

http://pastie.org/pastes/6357623/text

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56673/rosmake-fails-with-c++/clang-errors/) by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2013-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check the troubleshooting [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source#orocos_kdl_fails_on_rosmake_-a).

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2013-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-03-01**:
Thanks, I evidently missed that one!

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-03-01**:
@Hsang91: No luck, same exact error after doing that and rerunning rosmake!

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-03-01**:
Also I'm not sure if that will solve the errors of the form   `/Users/alex/ros_ws/visualization_tutorials/rviz_plugin_tutorials/src/drive_widget.cpp:114:24: error: variable length array of non-POD element type 'QPointF' QPointF right_track[ step_count ];`. Thoughts?

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-03-01**:
Sorry, then I do not know :)

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-03-01**:
No worries, cheers anyway! Let's see if anyone else has some inspiration. :)

**Comment by [Noldorin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4216/noldorin/) on 2013-03-01**:
@Hsang91 (and others): Interesting... did you notice that the log has both `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64` (one occurrence) and `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386` (one occurrence). How odd...